# Adding a .htm file to an IIS website asks for username and password instead of displaying the page

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

This is probably a simple fix, but I am having trouble googling the answer. What I have done was make a copy of a page that is currently on the site and renamed it. So for example I made a copy of page1.htm and renamed it to page1temp.htm. Now when I try to navigate to page1temp.htm it won't display the page, but instead asks for a username/password. If I navigate to page1.htm it still works as expected. I'm not sure what I am missing here. I am using IIS on a Windows Server 2003 R2.

I'm not sure what I need to change in IIS to get the page to display properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the NTFS permissions of the file (for example, by right-clicking on the file in Windows Explorer and checking the Security settings). Compare the permissions for both files. Chances are that the user used for anonymous authentication of your web site (might be IUSR_something) has permissions to read one file but not the other.